# Name of this glassware?

Tags: equipment

Could you tell me the name of this glassware? I found it in the laboratory with a label that says "container of stoichiometry", but I have not found more information about it, especially about the uses that it could give.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe what the glass tube inserted through the large screw cap looks like inside (or where does it lead)? It's hard to see on the photo due to the glare.

Comment: To follow-up on @andselisk's comment, can you just remove it and take a separate picture of it, please?

Comment: Looks somewhat like this: https://chemglass.com/distillation-receiving-vessels-cylindrical-chemrxnhub

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a vessel for sublimation. The tube going in the top would be filled with cold liquid making a tiny cold finger. The crude mixture is put in the cylindrical cup at the bottom. A vacuum is pulled from the bottom to lower the pressure. The side arm is for pressure release. After the material sublimates and deposits on the cold finger, it can be removed with the pure material on it in order to easily recover the material.

Comment: Usually, the sublimation apparatus doesn't have an adapter at the bottom for two different input/ouputs...

Comment: Yes, but having a three-way valve there would allow you to break the vacuum in the line while keeping a vacuum in the vessel if you don't have a valve in your vacuum line to do that. Just a possibility.

Comment: That's a good point, Andrew. I just would have expected such a joint to be at the top.

Comment: With regard to the label reference to stoichiometry, it could have been used to sublimate $\ce{I2}$ for use in iodometric titrations?

Comment: Perhaps it might also be connected to a nitrogen / argon line if a cycling vacuum / nitrogen distribution line isn't in place. Surely it is a cold finger.